How to apply css to HTML element used within set:html directive in Astro
Astro v 4.0.8
I have a parent Astro component which calls a child Astro component and I am passing an HTML string to the child Astro Component and it works using set:html.
Now I want to add CSS to that HTML element. How do I do this?
parent.astro


 <Child title="Child" description="text with html element <mark> marked data </mark>"/>

child.astro
---
const { title, description } = Astro.props;
---

<section>
  <h1>{title}</h1>
  <span set:html={description} />
</section>

<style>
  h1 {
    text-transform: capitalize;
    font-size: 3rem;

  span {
    & mark {
      padding-inline: 0.5rem;
      font-style: italic;
      color: blue;
    }
  }
</style>


But this style of mark doen't get applied. I've checked in Firefox and the latest version of Chrome.
How can I apply the CSS without using importing global.css?

Style tags are scoped by default, this means the tag will only apply styles to elements directly inside the file. You can target elements outside the scope of your file using a :global() selector:
<style>
  h1 {
    text-transform: capitalize;
    font-size: 3rem;

  span :global(mark) {
    padding-inline: 0.5rem;
    font-style: italic;
    color: blue;
  }
</style>


Global Styles
Scoped Styles


Does adding global will apply all mark element in the page

No because :global(mark) is a child of the scoped selector span
